# Periodic waves traveling on an ideal flat sea and the reflection of the Sun

Tags: waves, reflection

Suppose sinusoidal parallel waves (with equal wavelengths and amplitudes) are traveling in different directions on an ideally flat sea. The Sun is shining, let's say, $30^0$ above the horizon and the sea, and the sky is crystal clear.

Does it matter for what pattern in time (concerning the reflected Sun on these waves) we see, in which way the waves are traveling? Will all the patterns we perceive (thus for the different directions of the waves) be the same but stretched in time? Or...? The coastline where we stand is parallel to the horizon.

Comment: i may recommend you the book  by Minnaert "the nature of Light and color in the open air"    https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.3061436     that has a lot of fun with sun reflections on the sea

Comment: Thanks, patta! I've already some very interesting things!

Comment: @descheleschilder  In the case when we see "an ideally flat sea" there are no waves. Apparently, you mean that we must neglect the sphericity of the earth.

Comment: @Alex Trounev- I meant [without reference to the curved Earth: locally the Earth is flat enough (although there are many mountains to see)] that the sea is first ideally flat and then the waves are superimposed, so no other movements disturb the waves.

Comment: @descheleschilder You mean that there is no turbulence?

Comment: No, because this would influence the form of the waves. I mean with an ideally flat sea, a motionless flat heap of seawater (everywhere equally deep) without no motion at all (of course on the macroscopic scale).